# Customizing logic in process builder

Tags: salesforcedx, process-builder, error, campaign, process

[image: crietrai for proces builder]

can i customize the logic in pb like this
1 AND 2 AND 3 AND (4 OR 5) AND 6 AND 7

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Conditions section to customize the logic.

[image]